# Aplicar una función propia a una lista en R

Tags: funciones, r

Estoy empezando con R.
He tomado una muestra en 2D en una lista que contiene 2 vectores de 100 muestras aleatorias cada uno.

```
2dsample <- take_samples(2,100,c(-100,100));
```

También tengo una función que calcula los coeficientes `m` y `b` de la ecuación de la recta en forma `y=mx+b`. La recta se calcula aleatoriamente dado un rango de valores que delimitan un cuadrado.

```
vars <- sim_line(c(-100,100))
```

El objetivo es aplicar una función `f(x,y)=y-ax-b`. Donde x es un elemento de `2dsample[1]`, y es un elemento de `2dsample[2]`, a es la pendiente de la recta (m) y b es el desplazamiento de la recta. La función debe etiquetar la muestra con el signo de la función para cada par de valores (x,y)

Lo he intentado con esta línea:

```
result <- lapply(muestra2d,function(x,y) (y-(vars[5]*x)-vars[6]))
```

pensando que `lapply` toma un elemento del primer vector y lo copia en x, un elemento del segundo vector y lo copia en y y aplica la función, pero no es correcto.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Cómo puedo graficar la recta y los puntos a la vez? ¿Cómo hago para poner los puntos que resultan negativos de un color y los puntos que resultan positivos de otro?

Comment: Respondida en Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813289/apply-an-own-function-to-list-in-r

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(1L);
take_samples <- function(sample.num,elem.num,box) lapply(seq_len(sample.num),function(i) runif(elem.num,box[1L],box[2L]));
sim_line <- function(box) c(1,0);
box <- c(-100,100);
muestra2d <- take_samples(2L,100L,box);
vars <- sim_line(box);
signs <- sign(muestra2d[[2L]] - vars[1L]*muestra2d[[1L]] - vars[2L]);
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i');
plot(NA,xlim=box,ylim=box,xlab='x',ylab='y',main='plot');
abline(vars[2L],vars[1L]);
with(setNames(muestra2d,c('x','y')),{
    points(x[signs>=0],y[signs>=0],col='green');
    points(x[signs<0],y[signs<0],col='red');
});
```

[image: plot]

[Respuesta original en SO por bgoldst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813289/apply-an-own-function-to-list-in-r#35813517)